# Compatible way of choosing primitive roots of 1

Tags: number-theory, roots-of-unity

Let $K$ be any field containing all the $n^{\text{th}}$ roots of unity. Let $A = \{\xi_n\}_n$ be a collection of primitive roots of unity (so each $\xi_n$ is a primitive $n^{\text{th}}$ roots of unity). It is easy to prove that, for each $n,m$, the element $\xi_{n·m}^n$ is again a primitive $m^{\text{th}}$ root of unity, which $\textit{might not be}$ the primitive one $\xi_m$ which was already chosen. One can change $\xi_m$ by the new one $\xi_{n·m}^n$, but by doing so it could happen that other roots are not compatible anymore, for example both $\xi_{2·n}^2$ and $\xi_{3·n}^3$ are primitive $n^{\text{th}}$ roots of unity, which $\textit{may not be}$ the same.

My question is: is it possible to find a $\textit{compatible}$ collection $\{\eta_n\}_n$ of primitive roots of unity, meaning that the equation
$$\eta_{n·m}^n = \eta_m$$
holds for all $n,m$? It is easily verified that inside the complex numbers such collection can easily be chosen, taking for example $\eta_n = e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{n}}$.

I do not want to stick with the complex numbers case because my aim is to prove it abstractly, which I think it could be possible.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, this can be always be done (with the proviso that in characteristic $p$ you cannot have primitive roots of unity of order $p$ or any multiple of $p$). One way is to sequentially select elements $\xi_k$, $k=2,3,\ldots$, such that $\xi_2=-1$ and then select $\xi_{k+1}$ such that $\xi_{k+1}^{k+1}=\xi_k$, and also $\xi_{k+1}$ is of order $(k+1)!$. After that we have compatible roots of unity of factorial orders: $\eta_{k!}=\xi_k$. The rest can then be select as appropriate powers of $\xi_k$s.

Comment: (cont'd) If $m$ is a natural number, we can find an integer $k$ such that $m\mid k!$. Then declare that $\eta_m=\xi_k^{k!/m}$. It is easy to see that this is independent of the choice of $k$. Compatibility follows because of this.

Comment: Thanks Jyrki. One comment about the notation, which I am not understanding. The notation I am using is that either $\xi_n$ or $\eta_n$ are primitive $n^{\text{th}}$ roots of 1, so they have order $n$. Is that so in your notations for the $\xi_k$'s?

Comment: No. My $\xi_k$ is of order $k!$. I indexed it with $k$ instead of the factorial simply because then the indexing matches with their place in the queue that was constructred. On the other hand, my $\eta_m$ is of order $m$.

Comment: Ok, I have worked the details and everything works fine, thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome. Feel free to post the details as an answer. Then you get more feedback! No pressure, of course. Your choice.

Comment: I have worked a little bit on the problem, and now I cannot see why it is possible to select $\xi_{k+1}$ with order $(k+1)!$ and such that $\xi_{k+1}^{k+1} = \xi_k$. How is that the case? The only thing I can achieve is to find an element $\xi_{k+1}$ of order $(k+1)!$ such that $\xi_{k+1}^{k+1}$ is a primitive $k!$-th root of 1, so of the form $\xi_k^j$ for some $j$ coprime with $k!$. Why is the case that $j$ is also coprime with $(k+1)!$, no making possible to modify the element $\xi_{k+1}$?

Comment: Ok I think I figured it out, thanks anyway!